# Blazor loads too many dlls in the background

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Blazor is loading too many dlls in the background and therefore the opening speed is slowed down, can you help me how can I prevent it?
Uploaded files :

[image]

Client Side Csproj :

[image]

Comment: Well, looking at the list, they all seems necessary. The downside of Blazor Webassembly is that the .NET runtime and necessary DLLs have to be loaded.

Comment: We wait 50 seconds at each boot. It got a little weird. I did like Microsoft's document but same again

Comment: you're running in VS, try optimising & deploying the build with brotli or gzip compression, make sure you configure the server for brotli & gzip (brotli has much better compression, normally)